# cloud terminology, elasticity vs scalability and compute vs networking

Tags: azure, cloud

first of all would like to say a big thank you to all who is reading my questions, I really appreciate your time and hope to be able contribute back, second, I did see part of my question already asked in another thread but it does not answer it plus my questions have a bit different angle, so here it goes:

1. Does not elasticity already include scalability? I see scalability and elasticity go as two separate features of the cloud in service promotions, is there a technical difference or is it just marketing play of terminology?
2. I have similar confusion about compute and networking, does not compute power already include networking, I saw it being briefly displayed as two separate advantages of cloud service

Answer (score 0):

I will give it a try :) But it will largely be my understanding and less citing of provider documentation.

1. Elasticity vs. Scalability

I interprete elasticity as the capability to react to more or less daily variation in resource needs. Unlike reserved instances or your own server hardware "in the basement" the cloud provider offer both the resources and the managment tools to let you use varying amounts of compute, network , ... resources from hour to hour or day to day.
So elasticity (in my mind) solves the business need to react / adapt to changing demand that might follow a pattern like day / night or season / off-season but might be relatively stable from year to year or even week to week.

Scalability in my mind is more than everything the ability of these "hyper-scalers" to allow customers / you to grow your system continously and almost with no upper limit. So I would say the average (i.e.) weekly usage can go up every week for months after months and you wouldn't run out of upgrade options with the cloud providers to help you serve more and more requests.

2. Compute and Networking

The cloud uses "software defined networking" which abstracts all that hardware stuff like switches and routers from you as a user and offers connectivity options that would be hard to realize on your own / with traditional networking. So the networking capabilities of a major cloud provider are a feature set of their own, with lots of room for system improvements and capabilities. Therefor it is designed, serviced, billed... separately from other service classes like compute or storage.

A simple example or illustration of that might be a virtual machine (or multiple) that on their own as stand alone compute resources might have a network interface and a public ip attached to them. You can reach that machine, the machine can reach to internet (if you configure it that way) and you can install stuff on it. That's it - you have compute power.
But when you group virtual machines in i.e. application security groups and use these groups as objects in resources that allow, deny, redirect traffic internally or externally and maybe tunnel traffic to these compute resources to your on-premise resources (like in many cases Active Directory Domain Services) you start to use advanced networking capabilites. But obviously there's much more and networking can be one of the hardest parts of certification exams on cloud topics.